# sqlite: trouble selecting by real values

Tags: database, sqlite

I am using an sqlite database to store log data.

My table has a lot of 'real' type columns. When I try to execute queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE SomeNumber = 61;
SELECT * FROM log WHERE SomeNumber='61';
```

It will return nothing.

Queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE SomeNumber < 10
SELECT * FROM log WHERE SomeNumber > 10
```

Will return incorrect ranges.

Is there something wrong with my syntax ?

Thank you,

Comment: How did you generate the table, can you post the DDL?

Comment: Heres the table structure:

CREATE TABLE log (
Time text, 
TemperaturedegC real, 
ReceivedPackets real, 
Errors real
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you put into your table. Real numbers are almost always universally tricky. A "real" value of 61 might be stored as 61.0000000000001. The basic premise is, if you need to check for equality, prefer integers.

You might want to try:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE SomeNumber = 61.0;
```

It might also depend on how much precision you entered your original value with.

NB: I should point out that normally, an integer value like 61 is stored precisely even as a real. This is just a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem when using real number in query, and I '*solved*' it using the following request

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE SomeNumber = 61.7;
```

Becomes

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE SomeNumber between 61.7-0.00001 and 61.7+0.00001;
```